# Custom tooltip not showing in specific case

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I wish to have custom tooltips for my column chart, but something has me completely baffled.

When I add a row using the following code:

```
data.addRow([myArray[i].year.toString(), 0, myArray[i].value * 100, 'Tooltip Text']);
```

The tooltip shows up just fine when I hover my mouse over the column.

However if I do it this way:

```
data.addRow([myArray[i].year.toString(), myArray[i].value * 100, 0, 'Tooltip Text']);
```

My custom tooltip doesn't show.

Am I missing something obvious?

**EDIT**: My chart columns are set up like so:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
data.addColumn('number', '');
data.addColumn('number', '');
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
```